# MVVM shared between Win8 and WP8 (2 pages in one page)

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

We have a Windows Phone 8 application that uses MVVM. There are a couple of pages that work in the following way. Page 1 has some buttons and when one of them is clicked, page 2 is opened.

Now we want to migrate our application to Windows 8. Because of the bigger screen size, we can actually display both the buttons and the content on the same page (see the attached picture). Basically we are going to have a single screen on which we dynamically change a part of it (the right side with green)

We would like to share the view models between the two application. Is there a pattern to use for something like this?

There are a few alternatives that we investigated but we are not sure which one is correct:

1. Should "some content" (the second page in WP8) be a user control in the windows app?
2. Should we create a completely new view model for the Win8 that has the code from multiple view models in the WP8 app? This sounds like a bad idea though because we have about 6 view models in the WP 8 app that are now displayed on the same page in the win app.
3. Should the Win 8 view models somehow "contain" the other view models?
4. Should the dynamic content (the green box) have its own MVVM?

Ideas? Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends too much on your application to give any definite answer. But since pressing the buttons will load different content in the W8 app, MVVM can solve this without too much problems.

So, in WP8 app pressing the buttons issues a message that triggers navigation. In W8 you can change that message handler to destroy user control and create new one. In WP8 app your second screen was a standalone page with its own view model, there is no reason to not have a user control on W8 using that same view model.

However, you have to write UI from scrath since XAML cannot be shared.